# What is the complete list of empire rank countries?

Tags: europa-universalis-iv

I can't find it anywhere, only country I can find with an Empire rank is Byzantium.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the note saying which countries can be granted with an empire title via decision: http://www.eu4wiki.com/Government#Government_rank. The only starting empire in 1444 is Byzantium.

Update: looks like I was wrong. Ming also starts am empire, but it has it's own issues (50% autonomy, celestial empire government, mandate of heaven etc)

Comment: People suggested, that in the current version (1.16) Ethiopia also starts as a Coptic empire with East-African tech group (160% tech cost)